# Bounded type parameters - get type

Tags: java

I have such class:

```
public abstract class Test<T extends List<?>> {

    public abstract void handle(? arg);// ? - obviously won't work

}
```

Is there any way to "know" the type of list element in the Test's subclass?

Comment: You could use a named generic type parameter instead of `?`

Comment: Did you consider `Test<T>` and `handle(List<T> arg);`?

Comment: @khelwood where? can you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a named generic type parameter instead of `?`.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class Test<E, T extends List<E>> {

    public abstract void handle(E arg);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that should work, I'd be great if Java allowed me to write it like this: `class Test<T extends List<T2>>`. The current one is confusing and more complicated. Also, it would be nice to put `?` instead of `T` as I don't care about the `T` type